# How to locate an ubuntu file by size

Tags: ubuntu

I need to locate a file that has exactly 621658 bytes, I know it exists but not where. Is there any command that I could run that would locate a file based off the size of it?

Comment: do you want to read the man page of `find`?

Answer (score 3):

The following command would work:

```
find / -size 621658c -ls
```